# MSVCP100D.dll missing in windows 8 and need it for opencv 2.4.1

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MSVSP100D.dll missing working with opencv 2.4.1 in window 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089212/msvsp100d-dll-missing-working-with-opencv-2-4-1-in-window-8)

I have the following scenario:

I am trying to work with visual studio 2012, opencv 2.4.1 in windows 8.
Then when I try to run my app I got the following message error:

[image]

I know that question about missing MSVCP100D.dll are asked in stackoverflow before,
but something different happen to me: when I look for the dll in my computer I note
that I have a SVCP110D.dll which is probably a higher version of the first.

Someone can answer what's going on here.

EDIT:

I am very sorry I have some problems with connection and I don't realize that I ask the
same question twice, can anyone remove one of the 2 questions, maybe a moderator .....