# MSVSP100D.dll missing working with opencv 2.4.1 in window 8

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I have the following scenario:

I am trying to work with visual studio 2012, opencv 2.4.1 in windows 8.
Then when I  try to run my app I got the following message error:

[image]

I know that question about missing MSVCP100D.dll are asked in stackoverflow before,
but something different happen to me: when I look for the dll in my computer I note
that I have a MSVCP110D.dll which is probably a higher version of the first.

Someone can answer what's going on here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have the Visual C++ 2010 runtime installed. Visual Studio 2012 installs the 11.0 version, but it seems that your OpenCV has been compiled with Visual Studio 2010 and thus requires the 2010 runtime (10.0). You should be able to get it from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632

Because it's looking for the **D** version you can see it's built in Debug. Legally the run-time libraries cannot be redistribute in debug so you have these options:

- Install Visual Studio 2010 (at least VC++) so you'll have required files.
- Compile OpenCV in Release mode (so it won't need the Debug version of the run-time). You'll then need to install only the vcredist100 redistributables.

In every case to deploy your application you'll need to include both versions of the VC++ redists: version 11 for your application and version 10 for OpenCv (this is mandatory).

Notice that you *might* not be able to link binaries between Visual Studio 2010 and 12.

Comment: Hi @Anteru, I have the required run time redist package 10.0 (64 bit) and plus the file MSVCP100d.dll exists in some folder called sysWOW64. Could you tell me how to include this into VS2010? I have the exact same error as shown above. I'm running OpenCV 2.4.8 on VS10 and the build is successful.

Comment: There is no debug runtime package. Even if the file is in syswow64, it might be a different version. Maybe you have another update installed than what was used to compile OpenCV?